# JQuery: adding event handler (animation) on dynamically created element

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I need to get a dynamically created list item within unordered list to simultaneously be animated while being created.

My JQuery code setup:

```
$("button#enterAction").click(function(){
    var userAction = $('input#action').val();
$("ul.list-group").append('<li class="list-group-item" id="added-list-item">'+userAction+'</li>');
});
```

Now this code above creates a list item without animation to it. How do I add animation (say `.toggle` or `.animate`) to **only this** list item without affecting my whole unordered list?

I thought it could be achieved by firing a second event on dynamically created element with an ID `added-list-item` but I am not sure how to correctly write it down (syntax and functions used). Please help.

Comment: Animate how? Why not use CSS animations on a class given to the new element, those would trigger when the element is inserted ?

Comment: `id="added-list-item"` - Not valid

Comment: css animation would be the ticket here

Comment: But you can try the following `$("ul.list-group").append('<li class="list-group-item" style="display:none">'+userAction+'</li>').children(':last').fadeIn();`

Comment: @AlonEitan Your solution was very simple and effective. Thanks, problem solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a hidden element and then fade it out:

```
$("ul.list-group").append('<li class="list-group-item" style="display:none">'+userAction+'</li>').children(':last').fadeIn();
```

Working example:

```js
$(function() {
    $("button#enterAction").click(function(){
        var userAction = $('input#action').val();
        $("ul.list-group").append('<li class="list-group-item" style="display:none">'+userAction+'</li>').children(':last').fadeIn();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="action">
<button id="enterAction">Add</button>

<ul class="list-group"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of binding events Direct and Delegated. You are using the direct method which applies on existing elements only. To let event listener work on dynamic elements you'll need to use the second method.

Direct method: `$(selector).click(callback);`
Delegated method: `$(selector).on('click', callback);`

Delegated method will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

you could bind click to your new created item.
here is an example

```js
$("button#enterAction").click(function(){
    var userAction = $('input#action').val();
    var li = $('<li class="list-group-item" id="added-list-item">'+userAction+'</li>'); // create li 
    li.bind("click", function(){
    /// code goes here
    
    })
  $("ul.list-group").append(li);
});
```